# What is printf used for in PHP?

Tags: php, printf

When would I use printf instead of echo in PHP and why? I just don't understand why it's important to understand. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/php-printf-vs-echo-649387/

Comment: PHP, it seems to me, accumulated cruft from many languages, and there are several different ways to do everything. printf is there for the C programmers, echo is there for the shell scripters. something for everybody.

Comment: API documentation exist for a reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is used the same way it is used in C, to substitute formatted values into a format string.

There are literally hundreds of examples of its use on the [`sprintf` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

You can achieve some useful formatting of variables (zero padding, alignment, width etc) which would require an `echo` accompanied by several function calls.

For example, to right-justify and zero-pad a string to 10 characters, but truncate if longer than 10 characters:

```
 printf('[%010.10s]', $string);
```

vs

```
 $tmp = '';

 if (strlen($string) > 10)
   $tmp = substr($string, 0, 10);
 else
   $tmp = str_pad($x, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

 echo $tmp;
```

You can easily format numbers in octal, hexadecimal or binary without the clutter of running them through a function, storing the result in a temporary variable and passing it through `echo`. There are many, many more uses for the `printf` family of functions.

Comment: +1, contrary to the OP's question, `sprintf` is a really invaluable tool in many places.

Comment: That makes more sense why I would use it over echo. Thank you very much, I've been trying to google for a day or so, and my friend redirected me here! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

printf allows you to pass parameters so you can do this:

```
printf("My name is %s and my favorite color is %s", $name, $color);
```

or you can use echo which does the same thing but its not as clean:

```
echo "My name is $name and my favorite color is $color"
```

It just which one you prefer.

Comment: This technique becomes all the more important for translations with embedded variables: `printf(__('Hello there, %s, how are you?'), $username)`, the translated string is `こんにちは%s、お元気ですか？`.

Comment: At work, we use this in combination with Zend_Translate all the time.

Answer (score 2):

1. printf — Output a formatted string: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php
2. echo — Output one or more strings: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` allows you to format the variables in a certain way. For example, you can be sure that something that gets put in `%d` always gets displayed as a number. You can display floating point numbers with a certain number of digits after the decimal point. You can display numbers in scientific notations. You can convert numbers to octal/hex.

If you wanted to do any of the above using echo, you'd need to call some function or another before putting those variables inside a double-quoted string. Knowing how to use `printf()` makes your job simpler.

And it gets even more powerful when you can grab the output using `sprintf()`.